# Python: Iterating through odeint solution array to find max and min in waveform

Tags: python, arrays

I'm still relatively new to Python and I've been attempting to iterate through a solution array obtained from odeint to no avail.  I've tried many different things and get a slew of errors no matter which way I go about it.  The odeint result is a waveform and I'm attempting to find all the maximum and minimum voltages to calculate midpoint, etc.  I have this working in Matlab and posted the code so you can see what my goal is:

```
for i = 1:length(t)-2
  if Y((i+1),1) > Y(i,1) && Y((i+1),1)>Y((i+2),1)
    max = [max ,[t(i+1); Y((i+1),1)]];
  end

  if Y((i+1),1) < Y(i,1) && Y((i+1),1)< Y((i+2),1)
    min = [min, [t(i+1); Y((i+1),1)]];
  end
end

%remove any max not followed by min & mins not following a max for mdpt calc
if max(1,1)>min(1,1)
  min(:,1) = [];
elseif min(1,end)<max(1,end)
  max(:,end) = [];
end

midpt = [((max(1,:)+(min(1,:)))/2);(((max(2,:))+(min(2,:)))/2)];
```

I apologize if this code is bad, I'm still new to programming and don't often  approach things the right way.  Here is a piece of the python code so you can see what I need to loop:

```
t = linspace(0,3500,350000)
y_init = [-50, -50, 0.027, 0.891, 0.033, 0.051, 0.499,
       0.019, 0.043, 0.031, 0.000, 0.062, 0.22, 
       0.008069, 0.560552, 0.045224, 1.060]

sol = odeint(dy_dt, y_init, t)
S0 = sol[:, 0]
```

I need to loop through S0 here like in the matlab code.  I think my main problem is indexing the array so that I call the value of S0.  I tend to get a not callable or float64 error and was hoping for some advice.

Comment: Just to clarify - are the values in S0 floats?

Comment: Yes,  i think that's why I'm having a problem. I've gotten numpy.float64 errors several times.

Comment: Was my answer useful, or was I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Yep, I still have to work out the oo methodology, but that will come with time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate though the values in S0 you just need to do this...

```
for val in S0:
   do something with val...
```

You don't need to worry about the indexes like you do in MATLAB because you are able to iterate over objects in python. The MATLAB-like way implemented in python would look something like this...

```
for i in range(0,len(S0))
   do something with S0[i]...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was finally able to get this to work using the second method.  My issue was only using...for i in range(len(S0[1:-2])) and not fulfilling the start argument with a 0.